# why is custom validator not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I created a custom Validator called `threeNumbers` what it does is that it accepts only three digit numbers. But when I applied it to the `username` field it throws an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` and
`formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // form controls validation specicified in the class for the Reactive Forms
    this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [null, [Validators.required, this.threeNumbers.bind(this)]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})')]],
      address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      select: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
    this.dropDownArr = this.dropdown.getData();
    // this.personDetail = {
    //   name: '',
    //   email: '',
    //   address: '',
    //   chosenCourse: ''
    // };
    this.personDetail = this.fieldData.getPersonData();
    console.log(this.courseForm);
  }

  threeNumbers(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.value.length < 3 && typeof control.value !== 'number') {
      return { 'greater than 3 numbers': true };
    }
    return null;
  }

//HTML template

<!-- Form with three inputs and one dropdown which intializes with data from service on intialization and validates with min and maxlength-->
<section class="container">
  <!-- ngSubmit calls the function onSubmit on submitting the form  -->
  <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' [formGroup]='courseForm'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" name="name"
          [ngClass]="{inValid: !courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched, valid: courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched}">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched">Please enter a valid username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- username input ends here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <!-- CSS class applied based on validation -->
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" name="email" [ngClass]="{inValid: !courseForm.get('email').valid && courseForm.get('email').touched, valid: courseForm.get('email').valid && courseForm.get('email').touched}">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!courseForm.get('email').valid && courseForm.get('email').touched">Please Enter a valid email</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- email input ends here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputAddress" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Your Address" formControlName="address" name="address"
          [ngClass]="{inValid: !courseForm.get('address').valid && courseForm.get('address').touched, valid: courseForm.get('address').valid && courseForm.get('address').touched}">
        <!--Display error message on MinLength and MaxLength Validation-->
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="courseForm.get('address')?.errors?.required && courseForm.get('address').touched">Please Enter Your Address</span>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(courseForm.get('address')?.errors?.minlength?.requiredLength !== courseForm.get('address')?.errors?.minlength?.actualLength) && courseForm.get('address')?.touched">Address should be at least 10 characters long</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- address input ends here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose Course</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" formControlName="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="select" [ngClass]="{inValid: !courseForm.get('select').valid && courseForm.get('select').touched, valid: courseForm.get('select').valid && courseForm.get('select').touched}">
          <option [value]="selectedOption" [disabled]="true">Choose Your Course</option>
          <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr; index as i"  [ngValue]="data.course">{{data.course}}</option>          
        </select>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!courseForm.get('select').valid && courseForm.get('select').touched">Please choose a Course</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- select input ends here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]=!courseForm.valid>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="resetForm(f)">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- submit and reset buttons ends here -->
  </form>
</section>
<!-- section displays the submited form data in the view -->
<section class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Registered users</div>

    <!-- List group -->
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let person of personsList">username:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{person.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; email:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{person.email}}
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Address: &nbsp;&nbsp;{{person.address}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Course Chosen: &nbsp;&nbsp;{{person.chosenCourse}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you add your template?

Comment: [Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) docs.

Comment: You neet to check for `null` values `if (control.value && control.value.length < 3...`

Comment: like how can you explain some more

Comment: change `control.value.length < 3`  to `control.value < 3`

Comment: errors are gone but validation is not working

Comment: Validation is working `courseForm.get('username').touched`

Comment: no its not working. validation is only if input accepts three digit numbers

Comment: http://take.ms/nPIxp on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CklLgJGWnPfXFK8timOe?p=preview If username length less than 3 i see this error. Your validation function is not correct for your requirements

Comment: what sould it be can please write an answer

Comment: `it accepts only three digit numbers.` What do you mean? What are the correct values for username?

Comment: 123, 323, 838...   like this

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/S7RQtUdIZdjQpGmVtdKQ?p=preview

Comment: what did you do there

Comment: I changed `threeNumbers` function

Comment: whats the test methdo

Answer (score 2):

Like the built-in validators, you do not need to call `threeNumbers`, just pass it as a reference to `this.fb.group`:

You do not need the `bind` call, as Angular calls this internally. Change it to:

```
this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.required, this.threeNumbers]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})')]],
  address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
  select: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

At the moment, you're binding the `this` property. In this instance, `this` refers to your instantiated version of the class.

Remove the parenthesis essentially.

You could go the extra mile and make your `threeNumbers` method static since a validator should not depend on any local variables - the Angular default validators are static.

```
public static ThreeNumbers(control: FormControl) {
  if (control.value.length < 3 && typeof control.value !== 'number') {
    return { 'greater than 3 numbers': true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

I would also recommend passing an empty string `''`, instead of `null` to each control initialisation. This helps with a consistent state. N.b. on that note, you have a 'typeof' check, if this FormControl is bound to an input, then `typeof` will always be a string.

I have made amends - see above.