# restrict input field to numbers only using custom validator angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-forms

I researched a lot to find solution to this but none of the stakoverflow question has an accepted answer. So ive done my research and couldnt find an answer.

What I want the custom validator to do it that it should only take numbers as input and only three digit numbers like, 838, 892,183,234.. so on

Rightnow it accepts characters as well.

```
  threeNumbers(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.value && !/[0-9\+\-\ ]/.test(control.value) && control.value.length < 3) {
      return { 'greater than 3 numbers': true };
    }
    return null;
  }

}

this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
  username: [null, [Validators.required, this.threeNumbers, Validators.maxLength(3)]],
  email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})')]],
  address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
  select: [null, [Validators.required]]
});
```

// html template

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' [formGroup]='courseForm'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" name="name"
          [ngClass]="{inValid: !courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched, valid: courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched}">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!courseForm.get('username').valid && courseForm.get('username').touched">Please enter a valid username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This may just be improving the regex youre using.

Comment: ive tried many other regex as well but its accepting characters as well not just numbers. If you could suggest a pattern, ill try it

Comment: [0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: no not working its accepting characters as well

Comment: I am putting it in https://regex101.com and 3 charcter strings are not being accepted

Comment: then it must not be regex someother problem

Comment: You also appear to be negating your regex which means anything but that. Is that `!` on purpose?

Comment: removed the negation also but still not working

Comment: I think you need to use Validator.compose(this.threeNumbers). It shouldnt go straight into the array like that it needs to be wrapped in something for custom angular validation

Comment: when using Validators.compose. It throws this error:  [ts]
Argument of type '(control: FormControl) => { 'greater than 3 numbers': boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type '(control: FormControl) => { 'greater than 3 numbers': boolean; }'.
(method) AppComponent.threeNumbers(control: FormControl): {
    'greater than 3 numbers': boolean;
}

Comment: My plunker didn't help??? https://plnkr.co/edit/S7RQtUdIZdjQpGmVtdKQ?p=preview

Comment: Your question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447270/why-is-custom-validator-not-working

Comment: strangley it works in plunker but not in my code. I wouldve recorded a gif of that but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Just copy `threeNumbers` method

Comment: yes copied it and it worked but why can you please explain that code a little

Comment: `/^\d+$/.test(control.value)` it is regular expression that will pass only numbers. So if there is some value (`control.value`) and it has only numbers (`/^\d+$/.test(control.value)`) and value contains only 3 symbols (`control.value.length === 3`) then i tell angular that it's valid value(`return null`) otherwise i return object `{ 'error': true }` that tells angular that value is not valid

Answer (score -1):

call below function on (blur) -

```
validator(val){
if(val.length === 3){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}
make input type="number", it will stop taking alphabets.

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering. I want to do it through custom validator

Comment: anything which doesn't come in built , we call them custom. And here i have asked you to call above method on blur. Something like this:-
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="field1" (blur)="validator(field1)"/>